# Pygame AttributeError no attribute 'display'

Tags: python, pygame, tiling, pygame-surface

I'm trying to learn Python and Pygame by making a 2D tile-based platformer. Right now I'm stuck on the "tile-based" part. This is my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

#Just defining some variables
windowWidth = 640
windowHeight = 480
mapWidth = windowWidth // 32
mapHeight = windowHeight // 32
tilesize = 32
speed = [1, 1] #Array/List declaration
black = (0,0,0) #Tuple declaration

#intended to create a 2d list of subsurfaces    
def create_map():
    floor = pygame.image.load("rect_gray0.png")
    map = []
    for x in range(mapWidth):
        line = []
        map.append(line)
        for y in range(mapHeight):
            line.append(floor.subsurface((0,0,tilesize,tilesize)))

    return map


if __name__ == '__main__':

    pygame.init()
    print("Initializing")

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight))
    map = create_map()

    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        screen.fill(black)

        for x in range(mapWidth):
            for y in range(mapHeight):
                #for each subsurface in the map, blit it to the screen.
                tile = map[x][y]
                screen.blit(tile, (x*tilesize, y*tilesize))

        screen.display.flip()
```

When I run the code, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dementeddr\workspace\TheWaterIsRising\src\default\RisingMain.py", line 59, in <module>
    screen.display.flip() 
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'display'
```

I've googled around and I've seen plenty of other attribute errors, but nothing about the 'display' attribute. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you everything you need to know:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dementeddr\workspace\TheWaterIsRising\src\default\RisingMain.py", line 59, in <module>
    screen.display.flip()
```

The above portion shows the exact line of code where the problem occurred `screen.display.flip()`

```
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'display'
```

`screen` is of type `pygame.Surface`, which doesn't have a `display` attribute so something is wrong. Looking at a tutorial such as http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/intro/intro.html shows that you should be calling [pygame.display.flip()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) instead. Try replacing that line and see if it runs.

Good luck :)

Comment: Perfect. Awesome, thank you. The dumb thing is I *was* going off of that tutorial for this. I guess I miswrote it while modifying my code.